# I want to query the oracle db for getting count with multpile case clauses

Tags: sql, oracle

This is the query I'm trying:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(
  ( select distinct (
      (SELECT COUNT(*)  
       FROM PROCESS 
       WHERE STARTDATE > sysdate - INTERVAL '7' DAY) - 
      (SELECT COUNT(*) 
       FROM PROCESS 
       WHERE STARTDATE > sysdate - INTERVAL '14' DAY AND 
             STARTDATE < sysdate - INTERVAL '7' DAY)
  )as c3
  from process) /
  ( SELECT (CASE WHEN COUNT(*)=0 THEN (
      SELECT (case WHEN COUNT(*)=0 THEN 1  ELSE COUNT(*) end) 
      FROM PROCESS 
      WHERE STARTDATE > SYSDATE - INTERVAL '7' DAY  ) 
    ELSE COUNT(*) END)  
   FROM PROCESS 
   WHERE STARTDATE > SYSDATE - INTERVAL '14' DAY AND
         STARTDATE < SYSDATE - INTERVAL '7' DAY )
) AS ORDER_VOLUME FROM PROCESS;
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 295
```

can anyone help me with this query?

This is want i want

1)Get the count of when STARTDATE > SYSDATE - INTERVAL '14' DAY AND
             STARTDATE < SYSDATE - INTERVAL '7' DAY ,
2)if the count is 0 then
     get the count for STARTDATE > SYSDATE - INTERVAL '14' DAY AND
             STARTDATE < SYSDATE - INTERVAL '7' DAY ,
else set that count

if the count retrieved in step 2) is also 0 then set count as 1
else set the retrieved count

Comment: please add the sample data and the result you want by drawing the problem

Comment: The first thing you should to is to execute the two selects (before and after the `/` ) separately, so that you know better which part causes the error

Comment: @Andreas i'm having issue with the 2nd half (after the /)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an Oracle bug to me. The query seems syntactically correct.

However it seems you don't actually know exactly what your doing. The statement looks quite strange with DISTINCT two times, when you artificially have a value repeated for the number of records in table process, which makes absolutely no sense.

This is what your query would do, if the bug wouldn't prevent this:

```
select
  (count_last_week - count_week_before_last_week) / 
  case 
    when count_week_before_last_week > 0 then  count_week_before_last_week
    when count_last_week > 0 then              count_last_week
    else                                       1
  end as order_volume
from
(
  select 
    sum(case when startdate > sysdate - interval '7' day then 1 end) as count_last_week,
    sum(case when startdate > sysdate - interval '14' day and startdate < sysdate - interval '7' day then 1 end) as count_week_before_last_week
  from process
);
```

Check, if this is what you actually want and modify this query if necessary.

BTW: Be aware that you have `startdate > sysdate - interval '7' day` and `startdate < sysdate - interval '7' day` but no `startdate = sysdate - interval '7' day`. Plus: Do you consider time on purpose or would you rather work with trunc(startdate) and trunc(sysdate)?

Answer (score 0):

this part after '/'

```
SELECT  (
**--**CASE  WHEN COUNT()=0 THEN (
    SELECT  (
    case    WHEN COUNT()=0 THEN 1 
        ELSE    COUNT() 
    end ) 
FROM    PROCESS 
WHERE   STARTDATE > SYSDATE - INTERVAL '7' DAY ) 
ELSE    COUNT() 
END )
```

dont you think there should be a select where I marked it as '--' you innser sql has no select which is wrong or just remove that bracket and try like

```
SELECT  
CASE    WHEN COUNT()=0 THEN (
    SELECT  (
    case    WHEN COUNT()=0 THEN 1 
        ELSE    COUNT() 
    end ) 
FROM    PROCESS 
WHERE   STARTDATE > SYSDATE - INTERVAL '7' DAY ) 
ELSE    COUNT() 
END 
FROM    PROCESS**
```

Comment: similar with inner sql  : 
SELECT ( case WHEN COUNT()=0 THEN 1 ELSE COUNT() end ) FROM PROCESS WHERE STARTDATE > SYSDATE - INTERVAL '7' DAY

edit it as 
SELECT  case WHEN COUNT()=0 THEN 1 ELSE COUNT() end  FROM PROCESS WHERE STARTDATE > SYSDATE - INTERVAL '7' DAY

Comment: this is want i tried now                                    SELECT case when count(*)=0 then( SELECT case WHEN COUNT(*)=0 THEN 1 ELSE COUNT(*) end FROM PROCESS WHERE STARTDATE > SYSDATE - INTERVAL '7' DAY) else count(*) end FROM    PROCESS WHERE STARTDATE > SYSDATE - INTERVAL '14' DAY AND STARTDATE < SYSDATE - INTERVAL '7' DAY;                                                                     now also i'm having the same issue ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 16 Column: 41